# how can i create .env file in firebase for a react chat web app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MessagePane from './MessagePane';
import ChannelList from './ChannelList';

import { getMessages, getChannels, saveMessage, onNewMessage } from './storage';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
      channels: [],
      selected_channel_id: null
    };

    this.onSendMessage = this.onSendMessage.bind(this);
    this.onChannelSelect = this.onChannelSelect.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getMessages().then(messages => this.setState({messages}));
    getChannels().then(channels => this.setState({channels, selected_channel_id: channels[0].id}));
    onNewMessage(new_message => {
      const messages = [...this.state.messages, new_message];
      this.setState({messages});
    });
  }

  onSendMessage(author, text) {
    const new_message = {
      id: this.state.messages[this.state.messages.length - 1].id + 1,
      author,
      text,
      channel_id: this.state.selected_channel_id
    };

    saveMessage(new_message);

    const messages = [...this.state.messages, new_message];
    this.setState({messages});
  }

  onChannelSelect(id) {
    this.setState({ selected_channel_id: id });
  }

  filteredMessages() {
    return this.state.messages.filter(({channel_id}) => channel_id === this.state.selected_channel_id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ChannelList
          channels={this.state.channels}
          selectedChannelId={this.state.selected_channel_id}
          onSelect={this.onChannelSelect}
        />
        <MessagePane messages={this.filteredMessages()} onSendMessage={this.onSendMessage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default App;

i do not know how to make constant in .env file for firebase. please help me if anyone know about this and how to connect and access firebase database for real time reload. i have also change the rules but it does not  work for me.